# How to combine multiple reports without using subreports in MS-Access?

Tags: ms-access, report, subreport

I have several reports that I would like to have combined into one report that I can then export to PDF. I tried creating one master report with multiple subreports. However, as far as I can tell, subreports only include the Report Header and Detail sections. There is information in the Page Footer and Report Footer that is cut out of the subreport. Is it possible to either faithfully reproduce a report entirely in a subreport, or to combine individual reports and save it to one PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Accordig to [this page](http://hitechcoach.com/microsoft-office/access/68-reports/38-report-headers-and-footers):

> Page Footer - does NOT print. The Parent report is responsible for the page footer.

The page suggests a way around this issue.